# Group element by another element?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

The following SQL

```
with t(a, b) as (select 1, 2 union all select 1, 3)
select  t.a as 'X/A/@Id',
        t.b as 'X/A/b'
from    t
for xml path(''), root('ROOT')
```

returns

```
<ROOT>
  <X>
    <A Id="1">
      <b>2</b>
    </A>
  </X>
  <X>
    <A Id="1">
      <b>3</b>
    </A>
  </X>
</ROOT>
```

Is it a way to group the two `<b>` into `<a>` since the `Id`(`a`) are the same? (Is it a way to do it without using subquery if possible?) Expected,

```
<ROOT>
  <X>
    <A Id="1">
      <b>2</b>
      <b>3</b>
    </A>
  </X>
</ROOT>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select first column in the outer query and the second column in the inner query and then `GROUP BY` first column.

```
;with t(a, b) as 
(
    select 1, 2 
    union all 
    select 1, 3
)
select t1.a as 'X/A/@Id',
(
    SELECT T.B FROM T 
    WHERE T.a=t1.a
    FOR XML PATH(''), type
)as 'X/A'
from    t t1
group by t1.a
for xml path(''), root('ROOT')
```